# Replacing Variables in String at Runtime

Tags: javascript, regex, string, template-literals

Currently I am using the following to evaluate variables that are placed in strings at runtime:

```
newVal = eval("`" + newVal + "`");
```

So if I have the string:

```
"Hello from channel: ${erpVars["CommandChannel"]["name"]}"
```

And `erpVars["CommandChannel"]["name"]` has value `home`, then the resulting string is:

```
Hello from channel: home
```

There are other objects than just erpVars that could be holding matching values for the string, but this is just one example. It's also important to note that each string could have more than one variable that needs replacing.

I am trying to achieve the same thing without using eval(), as some of the variable values come from user input.

Comment: If you want to allow complex expressions like array indexing and object properties, you'll have to write a parser for those things if you don't want to use eval.

Comment: Try using the non-eval `looseJsonParse()` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Never_use_eval!)

Comment: @Barmar This seems to work, but I'm not sure how I would go about using it if one string has more than one variable that needs replacing.

Comment: A template string is not what you are looking for. You want a template engine. Don't use `eval`.

Comment: yeah... your current solution poses a major security threat. If I were a user of your system, I would register my name as `(() => {...setUpReverseSSH(); return "john";})()` and eval would execute my custom `setUpReverseSSH` function :P

Answer (score 0):

Your case sounds super nasty (you should never ever use `eval` in JS! It poses a major security threat! also it looks weird that you want to replace this sort of a string) and perhaps if you told me more about where you get your inputs from and in what form, then maybe we could find together a much better solution for this. On that note, this is how I would solve your issue in its current form.

```js
const newVal = 'Hello from channel: ${erpVars["CommandChannel"]["name"]}';

const strings = {
   erpVars: {
     CommandChannel: {
       name: "home"
     }
   }
};

const vars = newVal.match(/\$\{.+?\}/g);
let result = newVal;

vars.forEach(v => {
   let valuePath = '${erpVars["CommandChannel"]["name"]}'.match(/[\w\d]+/g).join('.');
   result = result.replace(v, _.get(strings, valuePath));
});

console.log(result);
```

[image]

Note that I'm skipping here the edge scenarios, like getting a null result from the `newVal.match` when there are no variables in the newVal, but that's easy to handle.
Also note that over here i'm using the lodash library in `_.get()` (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get). It's super popular for this kind of small tasks. Of course there are really a lot of other tools that allow you to extract a value based on a property path like `erpVars.CommandChannel.name` that is stored in the `valuePath` variable, including a crazy amount of instructions that tell you how to do it yourself.